# Sum of Logarithms with different bases

Tags: logarithms

it is my exercise to compute the numerical value of $x$ and $y$, where $$x:=\log_{20}(100)+\log_{100}(20),\\
y:=\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(70)+\log_{\frac{1}{10}}(200)+\log_{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{1}{100}.$$

In order to do so, I tried to simplify the expressions in various ways (by using the usual rules of logarithm), but I can not do it in a satisfactory way, such that the values are obvious. Is there any trick you can tell me which might work?

Let my show you, for example, what I tried to find $x$ explicitly. First I observed that the terms $\log_{20}(100)$ and $\log_{100}(20)$ do not seem to be computable individually. As I said before, I tried then to manipulate it in various ways, but I always get stuck, e.g.:

$$x= \log_{20}(100) + \frac{1}{\log_{20}(100)}=?\\
x= 2 \log_{20}(5)+ 2\log_{20}(2)+ 2\log_{100}(2)+ \log_{100}(5) = ?$$
etc.

I would appreciate your help very much!

Best

Comment: For the 1st eqn, note that $(20)^a = 100 \implies 100^{(1/a)} = 20.$

Comment: @user2661923 How will you find out the value of $\alpha$?

Comment: @Forester Since $\log_{10}~2$ is transcendental, I would regard it as reasonable to set $r = \log_{10}~2$ and then express the computation in terms of $r$.

Comment: Re my first comment, $a$ is clearly a transcendental number, so the only real issue is whether there is any dramatic simplification inherent in $\left(a + \frac{1}{a}\right).$

Comment: Are you supposed to compute the numerical value accurate to a fixed set of decimal places (e.g. accurate to 3 decimal places)?  My calculator gives $\log_{10}~20 \approx 1.30103 \implies \log_{100}~20 \approx \frac{1.30103}{2}.$

Comment: you can express $x,y$ in terms of $\log _z2, \log_z 3, \log_z 5, \log_z 7$, where $z$ any arbitrary positive number.

Comment: @ZAhmed True, and normally I would advise setting $z = 10,$ and go from there.  However, consider: "it is my exercise to compute the numerical value of $x$ and $y$...".  What **exactly** is the problem composer's intent behind *compute the numerical value...*?

Comment: May be you may have use $\log_{10} 2=0.3010, \log_{10} 3=0.4771,...$ etc. I don't see any thing else here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a formula to change the base of logarithms
$$\log_a b=\frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}$$
for instance
$$\log_{20} 100+\log_{100} 20=\frac{\log_{100} 100}{\log_{100} 20}+\log_{100} 20=\frac{1}{\log_{100} 20}+\log_{100} 20$$
Note that $$\log_{100}x=\frac{\log_{10}x}{\log_{10}100}=\frac{1}{2}\log_{10}x$$